# Multiple rows into one field on GROUPED results Mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a query results like this.

```
    status      count
    -----------------
    OTHER       5
    ATTENDED    74
```

I want result like this:

```
    OTHERS        ATTENDED
     5                74
```

Note this is already a grouped result. So I am thinking, Group_Concat might not work.

Query:

```
   SELECT CASE Rstat WHEN 1 THEN 'ATTENDED' 
                            WHEN 2 THEN 'TENTATIVE' 
                            WHEN 3 THEN 'REJECTED' 
                            WHEN 4 THEN 'OUTSTANDING' 
                            WHEN 6 THEN 'ACCEPTED' ELSE 'OTHER' END AS 'status',      
                            COUNT(Rstat) AS 'count' 
       FROM  `eStatus` 
       GROUP BY RSTAT
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Rstat = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ATTENDED,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Rstat = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TENTATIVE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Rstat = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS REJECTED,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Rstat = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OUTSTANDING,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Rstat = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ACCEPTED,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Rstat NOT IN (1,2,3,4,6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OTHER
    FROM eStatus
```

Comment: Awesome! Very close! But needed it in ONE row.

Comment: @KevinRave: Drop the GROUP BY. I left that hanging around by mistake.

Comment: Man! You are just awesome! Thanks! :-)